# Easiest way to build a cross-platform application

Tags: c++, cross-platform

I have read a few articles in the cross-platform tag. However, as I'm starting a fresh application (mostly a terminal/console app), I'm wondering about the easiest way to make it cross-platform (i.e. working for Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows). I have thought about the following:

- adding various macro/tags in my code to build different binary executables for each operating system
- use Qt platform to develop a cross-functional app (although the GUI and platform component would add more development time as I'm not familiar with Qt)

Your thoughts? Thanks in advance for your contribution!

**Edit: Sounds like there are a lot of popular responses on Java and Qt. What are the tradeoffs between these two while we're at it?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Do not go the first way. You'll encounter a lot of problems that are already solved for you by numerous tools.

Qt is an excellent choice if you definitely want C++. In fact, it will speed up development even if you aren't familiar with it, as it has excellent documentation and is easy to use. The good part about it is that it isn't just a GUI framework, but also networking, XML, I/O and lots of other stuff you'll probably need.

If not necessary C++, I'd go with Java. C++ is far too low level language for most applications. Debugging memory management and corrupt stacks can be a nightmare.

**To your edited question:**

- The obvious one: Java has garbage collection, C++ doesn't. It means no memory leaks in Java (unless you count possible bugs in JVM), no need to worry about dangling pointers and such.
- Another obvious one: it is extremely easy to use platform-dependent code in C++ using #ifdefs. In Java it is a real pain. There is JNI but it isn't easy to use at all.
- Java has very extensive support of exceptions. While C++ has exceptions too, Qt doesn't use them, and some things that generate exceptions in Java will leave you with corrupt memory and crashes in C++ (think buffer overflows).
- "Write once, run everywhere." Recompiling C++ program for many platforms can be daunting. Java programs don't need to be recompiled.
- It is open to debate, but I think Java has more extensive and well-defined library. The abstraction level is generally higher, the interfaces are cleaner. And it supports more useful things, like XML schemas and such. I can't think of a feature that is present in Qt, but absent in Java. Maybe multimedia or something, I'm not sure.
- Both languages are very fast nowadays, so performance is usually not an issue, but Java can be a real memory hog. Not extremely important on modern hardware too, but still.
- The least obvious one: C++ can be more portable than Java. One example is FreeBSD OS which had very poor support for Java some time ago (don't know if it is still the case). C++/Qt works perfectly there. If you plan on supporting a wide range of Unix systems, C++ may be a better choice.

Comment: Oh my...your answer pretty much sums up the different tradeoffs that I feel I need to think about when making the decision. I tried Qt a few years ago and gave up on it (definitely sucked at it). I can try asking for a friend to tutor me on it in the worst case scenario.

Comment: @stanigator, I recommend reading introductory parts of the Qt docs. As soon as you get the build system to work and figure out main technologies like signals and slots, Qt becomes easy to use and just does wonders.

Comment: dom4j is easy and best for edit/add values in XML better than in Qt. I've never done in Qt for XML working (encoding problems). In Java for dom4j it works perfectly. Compiling for Qt projects should be on each platform separately for Qt, but it's problem if you want repair error on specific platform and this can be pain. Qt for commercial apps need huge money for static library or commercial use. On Java you can develop apps in your own way and license. For security and throwing errors, I've seen wxwigets apps that can close apps unexpectedly for no reason. Java works fine.

Comment: But qt is paid isn't it? I saw monthly prices up to 300 US :/

Comment: @lxx, it used to be paid, then it went dual with GPL meaning you could use it for GPL software for free, and now it's dual with LGPL meaning if you comply with LGPL, you can use it for free even for commercial apps. You only need to pay if you need support and/or you can't comply with LGPL.

Answer (score 6):

Use Java. As much bashing as it gets/used to get, it's the best thing to get stuff working across any platform. Sure, you will still need to handle external OS related functions you may be using, but it's much better than using anything else.

Apart from Java, there are a few things you can run on the JVM - JRuby, Jython, Scala come to mind.

You could also write with the scripting languages directly( Ruby, Python, etc ).

C/C++ is best left for applications that demand complete memory control and high controllability.

Comment: Yes! In my opinion most things should actually be programmed in Java, it's easy, it's reliable and flexible enough. The only exception are high performance, realtime applications like game engines.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with the QT (or some other framework) option. If you went with the first you'd find it considerably harder. After all, you have to know what to put into the various conditionally compiled sections for all the platforms you're targeting.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a technology designed for cross-platform application development.  Here are two technologies I know of that -- as long as you read the documentation and use the features properly -- you can build the application to run on all 3 platforms:

- [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29)
- [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xulrunner) (Mozilla's Development Platform)

Of course, there is always the web.  I mostly use web applications not just for their portability, but also because they run on my Windows PC, my Ubuntu computer, and my Mac.

We mainly build web applications because the web is the future.  Local applications are viewed in my organization as mostly outdated, unless there is of course some feature or technology the web doesn't yet support that holds that application back from being fully web-based.

Comment: Actually, the web portion of this answer is great. If you can run something on a browser, then do it. It's by far the best deployment platform for any user end application.

Comment: @jetru - Agreed!  And to think I originally wasn't going to add that one before.  Users demand portability, but they also demand the power afforded to them on the desktop.  The web is capable of doing so much more than it was just 3 years ago.  Think what it will do in another 3 years!  Also, I don't really have a Mac.  I just added that for emphasis that if I did have a Mac, I'd be able to run all my programs :)

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest Github's [electron](http://electron.atom.io) which allows to build cross platform desktop applications using NodeJs and the Google's Chromium. The only drawback for this method is that an electron application run much slower than a native C++ application due to the abstraction layers between Javascript and native C++.

Answer (score 2):

If you're making a console app, you should be able to use the same source for all three platforms if you stick to the functions defined in the POSIX libraries. Setting up your build environment is the most complicated part, especially if you want to be able to build for multiple platforms out of the same source tree.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say if you really want to use C++, QT is the easiest way for cross-platform application, I found myself using QT when I need an UI even though QT has a large set of library which makes pretty much everything easier in C++.

If you don't want to use QT then you need a good design and a lot of abstraction to make cross-platfform application.

However I'm using more and more Python bindinq to QT for medium size application.
If you are working on a console application and you know a bit of python, you might find Python scripting much more comfortable than C++. It keeps the time comsuming stuff away to be able to focus on your application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned using the [FireMonkey (FMX) GUI Framework](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/fm-application-platform) with the [C++ Builder IDE](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder/starter/).

Using C++ Builder and FMX, you can very easily create cross-platform apps for Windows, MacOS, Linux, iOS, and Android.

I 100% recommend giving C++ Builder a try.